# strange characters: interaction of R and Windows locale?

Tags: windows, r, localization, locale

WinXP-x32, R-2.13.0

Dear list,

I have a problem that (I think) relates to the interaction between Windows and R.

I am trying to scrape a table with data on the Hawai'ian Islands. This is my R code:

```
library(XML)
u <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaii"
tables <- readHTMLTable(u)
Islands <- tables[[5]]
```

The output is (first set of columns):

> ```
>       Island            Nickname                                                                  > > Islands
>       Island            Nickname                                                                  > > Location 1    HawaiÊ»i[7]      The Big
> ```
>
> Island     19Â°34â€²N 155Â°30â€²Wï»¿ /
>   ï»¿19.567Â°N 155.5Â°Wï»¿ / 19.567;
>   -155.5 2        Maui[8]     The Valley Isle     20Â°48â€²N 156Â°20â€²Wï»¿ /
>   ï»¿20.8Â°N 156.333Â°Wï»¿ / 20.8;
>   -156.333 3 KahoÊ»olawe[9]     The Target Isle       20Â°33â€²N
>   156Â°36â€²Wï»¿ / ï»¿20.55Â°N
>   156.6Â°Wï»¿ / 20.55; -156.6 4   LÄnaÊ»i[10]  The Pineapple Isle
>   20Â°50â€²N 156Â°56â€²Wï»¿ /
>   ï»¿20.833Â°N 156.933Â°Wï»¿ / 20.833;
>   -156.933 5  MolokaÊ»i[11]   The Friendly Isle 21Â°08â€²N
>   157Â°02â€²Wï»¿ / ï»¿21.133Â°N
>   157.033Â°Wï»¿ / 21.133; -157.033 6     OÊ»ahu[12] The Gathering Place
>   21Â°28â€²N 157Â°59â€²Wï»¿ /
>   ï»¿21.467Â°N 157.983Â°Wï»¿ / 21.467;
>   -157.983 7    KauaÊ»i[13]     The Garden Isle     22Â°05â€²N
>   159Â°30â€²Wï»¿ / ï»¿22.083Â°N
>   159.5Â°Wï»¿ / 22.083; -159.5 8   NiÊ»ihau[14]  The Forbidden Isle
>   21Â°54â€²N 160Â°10â€²Wï»¿ / ï»¿21.9Â°N
>   160.167Â°Wï»¿ / 21.9; -160.167

As you can see, there are "weird" characters in there. I have also tried `readHTMLTable(u, encoding = "UTF-16")` and `readHTMLTable(u, encoding = "UTF-8")`
but that didn't help.

It seems to me that there may be an issue with the interaction of the Windows settings of the character set and R.

`sessionInfo()` gives

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.2-0.2
```

I have also attempted to let R use another setting by entering: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")`, but this yields the response:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
```

In addition, I have attempted to make the change directly from the windows command prompt, using: `chcp 65001` and variations of that, but that didn't change anything.

I noticed from searching the web that others have the issue as well, but have not been able to find a solution. I looks like this is an issue of how Windows and R interact. Unfortunately, all three computers at my disposal have this problem. It occurs both under WinXP-x32 and under Win7-x86.

Is there a way to make R override the windows settings or can the issue be solved otherwise?
I have also tried other websites, and the issue occurs every time when there is an é, ü, ä, î, et cetera in the text-to-be-scraped.

Thank you,
Roger

Comment: Cross post, +1 for Prof. Ripley: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-May/277057.html

Comment: Strange.  I run Windows 7 (64-bit) and your codes works perfectly on my machine.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: the docs for `Set.setlocale` suggest that changing the encoding in session is likely to be ignored and isn't recommended. You might try starting R from the command line and declaring the encoding as outlined [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

A not quite an answer:

If you look at the wikipedia page and change the encoding in your browser (in IE, View -> Encoding; in Firefox, View -> Character Encoding) to Western (ISO-8869-1) or Western (Windows-1252) then you see the silly characters.  That ought to mean that you can use `iconv` to change the encoding and fix your problems.

```
#Convert factors to character
Islands <- as.data.frame(lapply(Islands, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

iconv(Islands$Island, "windows-1252", "UTF-8")
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  It may be possible to get the correct text by using a different conversion (`iconvlist()` shows all the possibilities).

It is possible it simply strip out the offending characters, though this isn't ideal.

```
iconv(Islands$Island, "windows-1252", "ASCII", "")
```

Comment: I think it could be a correct answer. I would have guessed the first argument to be 'from' and second to be 'to', so why not: `iconv(Islands, "UTF-8", "windows-1252")`?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate the error, however looking at the help files is useful.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de")     # Solaris: details are OS-dependent
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.utf8")   # Modern Linux etc.
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")  # ditto
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE")  # OS X, in UTF-8
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "German") # Windows
```

For a windows you should use formatting like "English" or "Dutch_Netherlands.1252" to change these settings.

I tried to replicate your state

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Dutch_Netherlands.1252")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252"

library(XML)
u <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaii"
tables <- readHTMLTable(u)
Islands <- tables[[5]]
```

However I do not get the funny characters in console, in my own locale the ʻ was marked as , but still all functionality remained.

```
> Islands[1,1]
[1] Hawaiʻi[27]
8 Levels: Hawaiʻi[27] Kahoʻolawe[34] Kauaʻi[30] Lānaʻi[32] Maui[28] ... Oʻahu[29]
```

And these funny characters can be read easily, and found from the table.

```
> Encoding(as.character("Hawaiʻi"))
[1] "UTF-8"
> Encoding(as.character(Islands[1,1]))
[1] "UTF-8"
> grep("Hawaiʻi", as.character(Islands[1,1]))
[1] 1
```

If you still have problems it would rely elsewhere, however to change the locale under windows you have to use different names than Linux or OS X (see your own locale info for example). In Windows "Dutch" is probably enough.