# Importing an Excel file with Greek characters into R in the correct encoding

Tags: r, excel, import, character-encoding, iconv

I am having some trouble importing the following file:
http://www.kuleuven.be/bio/ento/temp/test.xlsx
into R in the correct encoding.
In particular,

```
library("xlsx")
read.xlsx("test.xlsx",1,header=F,colClasses=c("character"),encoding="UTF-8")
```

gives me

```
                                             X1
1                                     a-cadinol
2                                  a-calacorene
3                       a-caryophyllene alcohol
4                                   a-curcumene
5                                      a-elemol
6                                   a-muurolene
7                           a-terpineol acetate
8  ß-4-dimethyl-3-cyclohexane-1-ethanol acetate
9                                  ß-bisabolene
10                                  ß-bisabolol
11                                 ß-bourbonene
12                      ß-caryophyllene alcohol
13                                ß-cyclocitral
14                                   ß-farnesol
15                                   ß-selinene
16                         ß-sesquiphellandrene
17                            <U+03B3>-cadinene
18  <U+03B3>-Carboethoxy-<U+03B3>-butyrolactone
19        <U+03B3>-ethyl-<U+03B3>-butyrolactone
20                            <U+03B3>-eudesmol
21                           <U+03B3>-muurolene
22                         <U+03B3>-nonalactone
23                         <U+03B3>-octalactone
24                            <U+03B3>-selinene
25                       <U+03B3>-undecalactone
26                                   d-cadinene
27                                    d-cadinol
28                                  d-muurolene
29                              d-undecalactone
```

but the `a-`, `<U+03B3>-` and `d-` should be `alpha-`, `gamma-` and `delta-`

Any thoughts on how I could import my file in the correct encoding?

I am working on Windows, and `iconvlist()` gives me

```
  [1] "437"                     "850"                     "852"                     "855"                     "857"                    
  [6] "860"                     "861"                     "862"                     "863"                     "865"                    
 [11] "866"                     "869"                     "ANSI_X3.4-1968"          "ANSI_X3.4-1986"          "ASCII"                  
 [16] "ASMO-708"                "BIG-5"                   "BIG-FIVE"                "big5"                    "BIG5"                   
 [21] "big5-hkscs"              "BIG5-HKSCS"              "big5hkscs"               "BIG5HKSCS"               "CP-GR"                  
 [26] "CP-IS"                   "cp1025"                  "CP1125"                  "CP1133"                  "CP1200"                 
 [31] "CP12000"                 "CP12001"                 "CP1201"                  "CP1250"                  "CP1251"                 
 [36] "CP1252"                  "CP1253"                  "CP1254"                  "CP1255"                  "CP1256"                 
 [41] "CP1257"                  "CP1258"                  "CP1361"                  "CP154"                   "CP367"                  
 [46] "CP437"                   "CP50221"                 "CP51932"                 "CP65001"                 "CP737"                  
 [51] "CP775"                   "CP819"                   "CP850"                   "CP852"                   "CP853"                  
 [56] "CP855"                   "CP857"                   "CP858"                   "CP860"                   "CP861"                  
 [61] "CP862"                   "CP863"                   "CP864"                   "CP865"                   "cp866"                  
 [66] "CP866"                   "CP869"                   "CP874"                   "cp875"                   "CP932"                  
 [71] "CP936"                   "CP949"                   "CP950"                   "CSASCII"                 "CSIBM855"               
 [76] "CSIBM857"                "CSIBM860"                "CSIBM861"                "CSIBM863"                "CSIBM864"               
 [81] "CSIBM865"                "CSIBM866"                "CSIBM869"                "csISO2022JP"             "CSISOLATIN1"            
 [86] "CSPC775BALTIC"           "CSPC850MULTILINGUAL"     "CSPC862LATINHEBREW"      "CSPC8CODEPAGE437"        "CSPCP852"               
 [91] "CSPTCP154"               "CSWINDOWS31J"            "CYRILLIC-ASIAN"          "DOS-720"                 "DOS-862"                
 [96] "EUC-CN"                  "euc-jp"                  "euc-kr"                  "EUC-KR"                  "EUCCN"                  
[101] "eucjp"                   "euckr"                   "GB18030"                 "gb2312"                  "GBK"                    
[106] "hz-gb-2312"              "IBM-CP1133"              "IBM-Thai"                "IBM00858"                "IBM00924"               
[111] "IBM01047"                "IBM01140"                "IBM01141"                "IBM01142"                "IBM01143"               
[116] "IBM01144"                "IBM01145"                "IBM01146"                "IBM01147"                "IBM01148"               
[121] "IBM01149"                "IBM037"                  "IBM1026"                 "IBM273"                  "IBM277"                 
[126] "IBM278"                  "IBM280"                  "IBM284"                  "IBM285"                  "IBM290"                 
[131] "IBM297"                  "IBM367"                  "IBM420"                  "IBM423"                  "IBM424"                 
[136] "IBM437"                  "IBM437"                  "IBM500"                  "ibm737"                  "ibm775"                 
[141] "IBM775"                  "IBM819"                  "ibm850"                  "IBM850"                  "ibm852"                 
[146] "IBM852"                  "IBM855"                  "IBM855"                  "ibm857"                  "IBM857"                 
[151] "IBM860"                  "IBM860"                  "ibm861"                  "IBM861"                  "IBM862"                 
[156] "IBM863"                  "IBM863"                  "IBM864"                  "IBM864"                  "IBM865"                 
[161] "IBM865"                  "IBM866"                  "ibm869"                  "IBM869"                  "IBM870"                 
[166] "IBM871"                  "IBM880"                  "IBM905"                  "iso-2022-jp"             "iso-2022-jp"            
[171] "ISO-2022-JP"             "ISO-2022-JP-MS"          "iso-2022-kr"             "ISO-8859-1"              "iso-8859-13"            
[176] "iso-8859-15"             "iso-8859-2"              "iso-8859-3"              "iso-8859-4"              "iso-8859-5"             
[181] "iso-8859-6"              "iso-8859-7"              "iso-8859-8"              "iso-8859-8-i"            "iso-8859-9"             
[186] "ISO-IR-100"              "ISO-IR-6"                "ISO_646.IRV:1991"        "ISO_8859-1"              "ISO_8859-1:1987"        
[191] "ISO2022-JP"              "ISO2022-JP-MS"           "iso2022-kr"              "ISO646-US"               "iso8859-1"              
[196] "ISO8859-1"               "iso8859-13"              "iso8859-15"              "iso8859-2"               "iso8859-3"              
[201] "iso8859-4"               "iso8859-5"               "iso8859-6"               "iso8859-7"               "iso8859-8"              
[206] "iso8859-8-i"             "iso8859-9"               "Johab"                   "JOHAB"                   "koi8-r"                 
[211] "koi8-u"                  "ks_c_5601-1987"          "L1"                      "latin-9"                 "LATIN1"                 
[216] "latin2"                  "latin3"                  "latin4"                  "latin5"                  "latin7"                 
[221] "latin9"                  "mac"                     "mac-centraleurope"       "mac-is"                  "macarabic"              
[226] "maccentraleurope"        "maccroatian"             "maccyrillic"             "macgreek"                "machebrew"              
[231] "maciceland"              "macintosh"               "macis"                   "macroman"                "macromania"             
[236] "macthai"                 "macturkish"              "macukraine"              "macukrainian"            "MS-ANSI"                
[241] "MS-ARAB"                 "MS-CYRL"                 "MS-EE"                   "MS-GREEK"                "MS-HEBR"                
[246] "MS-TURK"                 "MS50221"                 "MS51932"                 "MS932"                   "MS936"                  
[251] "PT154"                   "PTCP154"                 "SHIFFT_JIS"              "SHIFFT_JIS-MS"           "shift-jis"              
[256] "shift_jis"               "SJIS"                    "SJIS-MS"                 "SJIS-OPEN"               "SJIS-WIN"               
[261] "UCS-2"                   "UCS-2BE"                 "UCS-2LE"                 "UCS-4"                   "UCS-4BE"                
[266] "UCS-4BE"                 "UCS-4LE"                 "UCS-4LE"                 "UCS2"                    "UCS2BE"                 
[271] "UCS2LE"                  "UCS4"                    "UCS4BE"                  "UCS4LE"                  "UHC"                    
[276] "unicodeFFFE"             "US"                      "US-ASCII"                "UTF-16"                  "UTF-16BE"               
[281] "UTF-16LE"                "UTF-32"                  "UTF-32BE"                "UTF-32LE"                "UTF-8"                  
[286] "UTF16"                   "UTF16BE"                 "UTF16LE"                 "UTF32"                   "UTF32BE"                
[291] "UTF32LE"                 "UTF8"                    "WINBALTRIM"              "windows-1250"            "windows-1251"           
[296] "windows-1252"            "windows-1253"            "windows-1254"            "windows-1255"            "windows-1256"           
[301] "windows-1257"            "windows-1258"            "WINDOWS-31J"             "WINDOWS-50221"           "WINDOWS-51932"          
[306] "windows-874"             "WINDOWS-932"             "WINDOWS-936"             "x-Chinese_CNS"           "x-cp20001"              
[311] "x-cp20003"               "x-cp20004"               "x-cp20005"               "x-cp20261"               "x-cp20269"              
[316] "x-cp20936"               "x-cp20949"               "x-cp50227"               "x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended" "x-Europa"               
[321] "x-IA5"                   "x-IA5-German"            "x-IA5-Norwegian"         "x-IA5-Swedish"           "x-iscii-as"             
[326] "x-iscii-be"              "x-iscii-de"              "x-iscii-gu"              "x-iscii-ka"              "x-iscii-ma"             
[331] "x-iscii-or"              "x-iscii-pa"              "x-iscii-ta"              "x-iscii-te"              "x-mac-arabic"           
[336] "x-mac-ce"                "x-mac-chinesesimp"       "x-mac-chinesetrad"       "x-mac-croatian"          "x-mac-cyrillic"         
[341] "x-mac-greek"             "x-mac-hebrew"            "x-mac-icelandic"         "x-mac-japanese"          "x-mac-korean"           
[346] "x-mac-romanian"          "x-mac-thai"              "x-mac-turkish"           "x-mac-ukrainian"         "x_Chinese-Eten"
```

I tried with many of these, to no avail... Unfortunately, I also don't know what encoding Excel saved my file in...

Also, is there any easy function in R that would allow me to convert all Greek alpha, beta, gamma and delta's (in original encoding) to "alpha", "beta", "gamma" and "delta" (ie written out in full)?
Or to do the reverse, ie convert "alpha", "beta", "gamma" etc written out in full to single Greek characters?

EDIT: regarding my last question I tried

```
togreek=function(compname) {
  n=as.character(compname,encoding="UTF-8")
  n=gsub("alpha","\u03B1",n)
  n=gsub("beta","\u03B2",n)
  n=gsub("gamma","\u03B3",n)
  n=gsub("delta","\u03B4",n)
  n=gsub("epsilon","\u03B5",n)
  n
}

tolatin=function(compname) {
  n=as.character(compname,encoding="UTF-8")
  n=gsub("\u03B1","alpha",n)
  n=gsub("\u03B2","beta",n)
  n=gsub("\u03B3","gamma",n)
  n=gsub("\u03B4","delta",n)
  n=gsub("\u03B5","epsilon",n)
  n
}
```

The function tolatin seems to work:

```
library("xlsx")
test=read.xlsx("test.xlsx",1,header=F,colClasses=c("character"),encoding="UTF-8")
tolatin(test$X1)
 [1] "alpha-cadinol"                                   "alpha-calacorene"                                "alpha-caryophyllene alcohol"                    
 [4] "alpha-curcumene"                                 "alpha-elemol"                                    "alpha-muurolene"                                
 [7] "alpha-terpineol acetate"                         "beta-4-dimethyl-3-cyclohexane-1-ethanol acetate" "beta-bisabolene"                                
[10] "beta-bisabolol"                                  "beta-bourbonene"                                 "beta-caryophyllene alcohol"                     
[13] "beta-cyclocitral"                                "beta-farnesol"                                   "beta-selinene"                                  
[16] "beta-sesquiphellandrene"                         "gamma-cadinene"                                  "gamma-Carboethoxy-gamma-butyrolactone"          
[19] "gamma-ethyl-gamma-butyrolactone"                 "gamma-eudesmol"                                  "gamma-muurolene"                                
[22] "gamma-nonalactone"                               "gamma-octalactone"                               "gamma-selinene"                                 
[25] "gamma-undecalactone"                             "delta-cadinene"                                  "delta-cadinol"                                  
[28] "delta-muurolene"                                 "delta-undecalactone"
```

But if I then convert back to Greek characters I again run into problems:

```
togreek(tolatin(test$X1))

 [1] "Î±-cadinol"                                   "Î±-calacorene"                                "Î±-caryophyllene alcohol"                    
 [4] "Î±-curcumene"                                 "Î±-elemol"                                    "Î±-muurolene"                                
 [7] "Î±-terpineol acetate"                         "ß-4-dimethyl-3-cyclohexane-1-ethanol acetate" "ß-bisabolene"                                
[10] "ß-bisabolol"                                  "ß-bourbonene"                                 "ß-caryophyllene alcohol"                     
[13] "ß-cyclocitral"                                "ß-farnesol"                                   "ß-selinene"                                  
[16] "ß-sesquiphellandrene"                         "<U+03B3>-cadinene"                            "<U+03B3>-Carboethoxy-<U+03B3>-butyrolactone" 
[19] "<U+03B3>-ethyl-<U+03B3>-butyrolactone"        "<U+03B3>-eudesmol"                            "<U+03B3>-muurolene"                          
[22] "<U+03B3>-nonalactone"                         "<U+03B3>-octalactone"                         "<U+03B3>-selinene"                           
[25] "<U+03B3>-undecalactone"                       "d-cadinene"                                   "d-cadinol"                                   
[28] "d-muurolene"                                  "d-undecalactone"
```

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Running those commands you provided works out perfectly fine for me, those Greek character display fine. My locale is `Japanese_Japan.932`, so I expect that `encoding="UTF-8"` is correct. This might have something to do with your environment settings. What does your `sessionInfo()` say?

Comment: Ha it says locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252     What should I change it to then?

Comment: Or could it be some problem with R studio perhaps?

Comment: It seems there is some problem with the way the output is displayed. If I type test=read.xlsx("test.xlsx",1,header=F,colClasses=c("character"),encoding="UTF-8")
test$X1    it shows OK. So maybe I should change my locale. If I try Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8') I get the error Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored though.... Others have reported the error too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881731/strange-characters-interaction-of-r-and-windows-locale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
`Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Greek")`

Comment: Do you know if this locale="Greek" is also a UTF-8?

Comment: @MariaProvelegiou sorry dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`library(stringi)`

```
?stringi
```

**Apply this to see your file codification**

```
stri_enc_detect("path-to-your-file/your-file.csv", filter_angle_brackets = T)

stri_enc_detect2("path-to-your-file/your-file.csv", locale = NULL)
```

**The first** one works for me.

Then apply the result in the `read.csv()`, as the example bellow:

```
    df <- read.csv("path-to-your-file/your-file.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ";", 
quote = "\"", na.strings = "", dec = ".", skip = 2, check.names = T, 
fileEncoding = "YOUR RESULT OF stri_enc_detect", encoding = "UTF-8")
```