# Turkish Character Encoding in R

Tags: r, encoding, turkish

Is there a way to change the character encoding system in R according to the Turkish language?

I tried to change the encoding while saving an R Script to iso-8859-9, windows-1254 or to latin5. The last encoding gave me the best results, however when I reload the R Script not all of the characters were saved properly. For example:

Original:

```
hâkimiyetinin
çıkıyor
```

Reloading (characters in the second example chrashed):

```
hâkimiyetinin
çýkýyor
```

Anyone an idea? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, I tried several things including Israel's answer but the only thing that helped me was changing the locale.

I just typed the following command into the RStudio console.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Turkish")
```

Now whenever I type İstanbul I get the dot on the I. Before I had it set to UTF-8 but it would still cause problems.

I found [this question about Greek characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916070/importing-an-excel-file-with-greek-characters-into-r-in-the-correct-encoding#_=_) but it's essentially the same principle. Just change "Greek" to "Turkish".

Answer (score 0):

This function should tell you which encodes are in your machine

```
iconvlist()
```

This should tell you in which encode is the string pal

```
Encoding(pal)
```

This should change the encode for pal

```
 Encoding(pal) <- "latin1"
```

This should translate pal to a certain encode

```
pal <- iconv(pal, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
```

and I don't know if this encodes are the ones you are looking for

```
"x-mac-turkish" or "macturkish"
```

hope this helps