# Cannot read csv file with greek letters

Tags: r, read.csv

I am having trouble reading a csv file in R that includes greek letters. I tried:

```
read.csv('C:/users/trinhsk/downloads/diospyros_1/Substances (7).csv',header = F)
```

This site ([How to detect the right encoding for read.csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806823/how-to-detect-the-right-encoding-for-read-csv)) suggested I try different `fileEncoding`s however none seemed to work. R is displaying the greek letters like so:

[image]

However in Excel it is like:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how can I read the Greek letters correctly? Thank you.The file can be dl'd here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K44FTvUFUWm5l-xwz58SgeSvj8lGYXTc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916070/importing-an-excel-file-with-greek-characters-into-r-in-the-correct-encoding) you could first try "UTF-8" as encoding, and if this doesnt work, simply set

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Greek")
```

Comment: hi thanks for your quick response. I tried that and it didn't seem to make any difference in the parsing. R still shows strange characters. I also tried UTF-8 and it gave me warning message: 'incomplete final line found by readTableheader' ...